# How to call methods from generic class in static class? java

Tags: java, generics, static

I have 4 classes: edge, graph, node, and shortestpath. I want to call methods from my graph class in the static main of my shortestpath class. The error i am getting is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method readFile() from the type graph". I would appreciate any help im stuck :(!

```
public class edge<E>{}
public class node<E> extends edge<E>{}

public class graph<E> {
   public node<E> BFS(E value)
   {
    if (adjList.isEmpty())
        return (null);

    ArrayList<node<E>> visitedNodes = new ArrayList<node<E>>(); 

    node<E> sourceNode = adjList.get(0);
    sourceNode.setVisited(true);

    visitedNodes.add(sourceNode); 

    node<E> currNode = null; 

    while(!visitedNodes.isEmpty())
    {
        currNode = visitedNodes.get(0);
        visitedNodes.remove(0);

        if(currNode.getData() == value)
            return (currNode);

        //ListIterator<edge<E>> itr = currNode.incidentEdges.listIterator(); 

        for(node<E> adjNode : adjList) 
        {
            adjNode = adjNode.getChild();

            if(!adjNode.isVisited())
            {
                adjNode.setVisited(true);
                visitedNodes.add(adjNode);
            }

        }

    }
    return (null);
}


public void readFile()
{
File file = new File("Enron-Email.txt");

try 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.trim().startsWith("#"))
        {
            continue; 
        }

        String[] tokens = line.split("\\t");

        Integer parent = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        Integer child = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

        addEdge((E) parent, (E) child);
    }
    scanner.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}    


    public class shortestpath{
public static void main(Integer source, Integer dest) {
    graph<E> myGraph = new graph<E>(); 
    myGraph.readFile();
    myGraph.BFS(source);    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke **non-static methods** from **static methods** you need to create an **instance** of the **class** and call that method on that instance.
so, In your case, you need to create an **instance of Graph class** and call `readFile()` method from your main method of **ShortestPath class**.

```
Graph<YourType> g = new Graph<YourType>(); //replace YourType with the type you want to pass like Integer, blah blah...
g.readFile();
```

EDIT:

```
graph<E> myGraph = new graph<E>();
```

should be

```
graph<Integer> myGraph = new graph<Integer>(); //Or some other valid types. 

E is just an representation of Element. provide a valid element type
```

Comment: WHen i do that i get a warning stating "graph is a raw type. References to generic type graph<E> should be parameterized"

Comment: @woody you have pass a type to your graph class.

Comment: I have done this and receive marker "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E"

Comment: @woody seems confusing, can you post the signatures of the class please .

Comment: @woody what is your Graph class expecting ?? Integer, String, any other type ?? check my EDIT :)

Answer (score 1):

You either have to make the `graph.readFile()` method `static` or call `readFile()` method on the `instance` of `graph` class.

In the first case it would look sth like:

```
public class shortestpath {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        graph.readFile ();
    }
}

public class graph {
    public static void readFile () {
    }
}
```

Whereas in the second case it would look sth like:

```
public class shortestpath {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new graph ().readFile ();
    }
}

public class graph {
    public void readFile () {
    }
}
```

Furthermore please not that even though in the code below I used class names with lower case (as you supplied them in the question) there is a general convention in Java world to name the classes using [upper camel case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UpperCamelCase).

Comment: i have tried this but receive this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E"

Comment: Making the method static produces that error ^. When i try the second i recieve warning "graph is a raw type. References to generic type graph<E> should be parameterized"

Comment: Ok. So you're using generic types. Try `new graph<edge> ().readFile ()`.

Comment: When i try `new graph<edge> ().readFile ()` i receive warning "edge is a raw type. References to generic type edge<E> should be parameterized". When i try `new graph<E>().readFile()` i receive error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E"

Comment: @woody is Edge an generic class as well, it seems so, u need to provide a type for your Edge as well, like Graph<Edge<TypeYouWantToPass>>

Answer (score 0):

In order to invoke an instance method you have to have an object on which to invoke it.

```
public class A
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A.someMethod(); // ERROR

        A a = new A();
        a.someMethod(); // Correct
    }
}
```

Comment: I receive error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E" when creating the new instance.

Comment: You are going to have to show your code.  Reduce it down to the smallest _complete_, _compilable_ example that gives you the error, and then edit your original post.